# Changing the position of UIView with out Autolayout

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have designed a UIView class in a nib. On a button Click I display the UIView as a customised pop up with animation.

Here is the code:

```
UIView* pickerView = [dataLoaderView newAnimationCurvePicker:self];
          //Animation will Start from middle of View
          pickerView.center = self.view.center;
          [self.scrollView addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:pickerView duration:0.5 option:curveValues[0]];
```

DataLoaderView is a UIView class

```
+(id) newAnimationCurvePicker:(id)pickDelegate
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"dataLoader" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *nibArray = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    dataLoaderView *me = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
return me
}
```

Animation Code:

```
- (void) addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
{
    // first reduce the view to 1/100th of its original dimension
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);
    view.transform = trans; // do it instantly, no animation
    [self addSubview:view];
    // now return the view to normal dimension, animating this tranformation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
        animations:^{
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 100.0, 100.0);
        }
        completion:nil];    
}
```

My problem is when I change the orientation of the screen, I can't position the UIView properly in the centre of the View

```
-(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {        
      UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"dataLoader" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *nibArray = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        dataLoaderView *me = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        me.center = self.view.center;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work for me. For some reasons I'm not allowed to use **Auto layouts**.

Comment: It seems that you create new instance in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and don't add it as a asubview. You should keep a reference to the originally created view and change it's position.

Comment: I would think you need to add constraints for your picker view for top edge and left edge (or horizontal center if scrolled content same width as screen) so that when you add it to the scroll view it positions using constraints. From iOS8 onwards, setting position with frame settings in an autolayout environment tends not to work. For the top offset you need to take into account the `bounds` x and y if the content has been scrolled. On rotation, the constraints need updated if not using centering. On iOS7 CGAffineTransformScale does not play well with constraints, so you may see issues.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel For some reasons Im not allowed to use Auto Layouts

Comment: @Losiowaty I tried using reference I can see the UIView changing its position, but that View is not responsive

Comment: @lcoder Looking at your code, you really want to create the views once and from then on only change the frame location. You seem to do a lot more in viewWillLayoutSubviews. Better would be to just check if the view has a superview, and if so position it based on the orientation. You could also do this more efficiently by detecting orientation change and doing it once per orientation change.

Comment: @Icoder - what do you mean "not responsive"?

Comment: @Losiowaty means subviews of that UIView is not responding to any actions

Comment: Okey, for me nothing in your question indicates this problem :) How do you access the subviews? How are their actions linked? Through `IBAction`s?